# Windows in taskbar are grouped by the parent app, rather than app

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

In the taskbar (aka Ubuntu Dock) windows are grouped by the parent application that launched them instead of the application

In the screenshot, it looks have one Chrome instance and two PhpStorm instances running when there's actually two Chrome instances. There's one Chrome instance within PhpStorm, which I can access by clicking PhpStorm and selecting the window in the list of thumbnail previews.

This happens because PhpStorm launched Chrome, but I want it to be grouped by application (like Windows).

[image: screenshot]